# fedora 22 multiple undefined reference errors when linking shared object

Tags: c, makefile, shared-libraries, fedora

I am trying to compile a C language library as a shared object on my new install of Fedora 22. The project compiled fine on my old install of Fedora 20. But now, when I run my makefile:

```
CC=gcc

vpath %.c src
vpath %.h inc


CFLAGS = -fPIC
INCLUDE = -Iinc -I/usr/include -I/usr/local/include
LIBPATH = -L/usr/lib -L/lib64 
LIBS = -lportaudio -lm -lpthread -ldl
OBJ_PATH = ./objs

SRCS = my_code1.c my_code2.c # etc.

OBJS = $(SRCS:.c=.o)

.PHONY: libmylib.so

all: libmylib.so

debug: $(CFLAGS) += -DDEBUG -O0 -g3 -DPD
debug: all
release: $(CFLAGS) += -DTESTING -O2 -DPD -funroll-loops -fomit-frame-pointer
release: all

%.o: %.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(INCLUDE) $(LIBPATH) $(LIBS) -c -o $@ $^

libmylib.so: $(OBJS)
    $(CC) -shared -Wl,-soname,libmylib.so \
    -Wl,--no-undefined $(OBJS) -lc -lportaudio -ldl -lm -lpthread
    mv libmylib.so ./bin
    mv *.o $(OBJ_PATH)

clean:
    rm $(OBJ_PATH)/*.o
    rm bin/libmylib.so
```

I get very many undefined reference errors:

```
my_code1.o: In function `func_in_my_code1':
my_code1.c:(.text+0x1b8): undefined reference to `func_from_my_code2'
my_code2.o: In function `func_in_my_code2':
my_code2.c:(.text+0x310): undefined reference to `func_from_my_func1'
```

The functions in question are most certainly defined in the code. Presumably these are compiled into .o files in the compile stage.

The exact same build environment worked on my previous fedora installation. I am at a loss as to why I should get these errors.

Also, if I compile without the `-Wl,--no-undefined` flag, it compiles fine, but when I try to load the library from another application, it tosses the same set of undefined errors.

This may have nothing to do with the new version of Fedora. It is possible that there are some environment variables or something that didn't make through to my new install, but I have no idea what they could be.

Comment: Apparently you, did not post the actual makefile. It's not possible to help you.

Comment: There is not nearly enough information in your post to even help you out a little, pasting the complete makefile would be a step in the right direction as @iharob already mentioned. I doubt the version of `Fedora` you're using is the cause of the issue but really, I'm unable to tell for sure...

Comment: I posted the entire makefile. I changed the names of the files, functions etc. to protect the innocent. There are dozens of files of source code, thousands of lines of code. I didn't think it was practical to upload the entire project. Is it clear that functions referenced in other files are the cause of the undefined references? I don't know what other information to give -- part of the reason I am resorting to stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently I now need to insert the extern keyword into these functions. The code compiled and ran perfectly well before... I would like to reiterate, for posterity's sake, that I did post the *entire* makefile in my question.

Comment: One final note. The functions that needed the extern keyword were all inlined.